# Optimizing an utility and penalty score on a 2D neighborhood

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, multidimensional-array, mathematical-optimization

My problem is the following.

Consider a large array A(u,v) indexed by (u,v) (e.g. an image) and a given reference position (u0,v0) inside this array. Each position (u,v) in A is associated with an *utility* score s(u,v), which is positive and arbitrary, and a *penalty* score p(u,v), which is negative and proportional to the distance between (u,v) and (u0,v0). I want to determine a neighborhood N (i.e. a set of *connected* indices (u,v)) around (u0,v0) which *maximizes* the sum of all utility and penalty scores on the neighborhood N.

This is a rather abstract description, but what would be an appropriate algorithm to approach such a problem ?

Comment: Unless there are negative values, choose the whole array, then you have the maximum utility and penalty. But I guess that is not what you want.

Comment: In general graphs, with general everything, this would be called "node-weighted prize-collecting Steiner tree".

Comment: [Demaine, Hajiaghayi, and Klein](http://cs.brown.edu/~klein/publications/planar-node-weighted-Steiner.pdf) (my advisor) gave a constant-factor primal-dual approximation for planar graphs. I'm not sure how difficult it would be to implement or whether it would be worthwhile.

Comment: @NicoSchertlerthe right, I did not explicitly said that penalty is negative.

Comment: Maybe a simple flood-fill approach is sufficient. This will not find a global optimum in any case, but it's easy to implement and might be appropriate for your case. Start at `(u0, v0)` and take all pixels where `s(u,v)+p(u,v)>=0`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Interesting, I think in my application a non-global optimum could be enough. I'll try that too, thanks.

Comment: Are we looking for the neighborhood of only a single point, rather than all points in the array? For example `N = foo(A,s,p,(u0,v0))`.

Comment: And by connected do you mean strictly connected to (u0,v0) or is this a full graph that can cover the entire image?

Comment: @wbest Ultimately I'll have to do the same for a few different (u0,v0), but not all points in the array. And for your second question, I don't get the difference between the two expressions. The neighborhood has to be connected to (u0,v0) though.

Comment: When I say "neighborhood" I usually refer to the 8 pixels directly connected to a given pixel.

Comment: @wbest Ok, by "neighborhood" I meant a region of the image more or less around (u0,v0), not just the pixels directly connected to it.

Comment: "More or less"? Does that mean it can include the entire image? Even if the image is say, 65535x65535 pixels? Or is the size of the neighborhood restricted?

Comment: @wbest yes, the neighborhood _could_ be the entire image. But I would like to find the best boundary (not necessarily the global optimum though) based on the utility and penalty scores I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick follow up. I have been working on this problem for some time and I have been able to obtain satisfactory results using a modified version of [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm).

More precisely, I considered the 2D array as a 4-connected graph and the reference position (u0,v0) as a starting position in the graph. I then defined the cost of an edge between two nodes to be a constant `cost_edge` and the cost of a path in the graph to be the sum of the edge costs along this path. As a heuristic for node (u,v), I used the difference between the maximum utility score on the array and the utility score of the current node: h(u,v) = s<sub>max</sub> - s(u,v). I also used one modification to the base A* algorithm: I do not use any destination node, however as nodes are being visited, I maintain the sum of utility scores for all visited nodes (nodes in the *closed set*, as denoted by the Wikipedia article) and I stop the algorithm when this sum becomes larger than a specified threshold `max_total_utility`.

This algorithm has two input parameters which I had to tweak according to my own definition of utility score:

- `cost_edge`, which controls the compromise to be made between the *locality* of the resulting neighborhood around (u0,v0) and the *greediness* to maximize the sum of utility scores
- `max_total_utility`, which controls the area of the final neighborhood

This provides appropriate (though not strictly optimal, in particular the heuristic may not be [consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic)) solutions to my problem because it minimizes the distance between the selected (i.e. visited) nodes and the input reference point, while being drawn by the heuristic to select first the nodes with high utility scores.

Note that I do not use the penalty score anymore, but since it was proportional to the distance between the current node and the reference position, minimizing the cost of the path from (u0,v0) to (u,v) is a good enough approximation to minimizing the overall penalty score.

Comment: Of course, I am still open to comments or other propositions.